# removing Object from a vector of pointer, 2D array of pointers and freeing its memory in one loop

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, stdvector

In my application, I have a 2D **Environment** that can contain **Agent** objects. To simplify calculations, my environment is made of two data structures :

1. A `Agent*** grid` to represents the 2D grid of pointers (if an agent is at a position, there is a pointer to it, otherwise its `nullptr`).
2. A `std::vector<Agent*> agents` to represents the list of agents in the environment. I use this data structure to prevent iterating over the entire grid when I need to update my agents.

Every time I update the entire environment, I would like to remove a portion of my agents from the environment according to a criterion. Thus, I want to remove the agent from the two data structures I described above and freeing the agent memory afterward. Also, to maximize efficiency, since `agents` can be a very big vector, I want to perform the remove  and the `delete` in a single loop.

My following (and incorrect) approach is the following :

```
void Environment::removeDeadAgents(){
std::vector<Agent*>::iterator it = agents.begin();

while(it != agents.end()){
    Agent* a = (*it);
    if(!a->isAlive()){
       grid[a->getY()][a->getX()] = nullptr;
       delete *it;
       it = agents.erase(it);
    }else{
        it++;
    }
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: You say your approach is _incorrect_, what exactly are the symptoms? Can you provide a [mcve] as required here please?

Comment: Unrelated: Poke around a bit and you'll find whole Internet sited devoted to mocking the Three Star Programmer.

Comment: I empirically found out that each time I used a triple-pointer, it was almost always because my design was bad.

Comment: Note: What little you have here is quite error prone. Have you considered using Smart Pointers? `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` would be a better fit, but I think you can do this with `unique_ptr`s owned by the `vector`.

Comment: *Also, to maximize efficiency, since agents can be a very big vector, I want to perform the remove and the delete in a single loop.* -- Your approach is not optimal at all.  For every time you call `erase`, the large vector has to be shrunk.  There are much better ways to do this without this cost (until at the very end).

Answer (score 3):

Your approach could be rewritten, but much more safely using [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)

```
#include <algorithm>

void Environment::removeDeadAgents()
{
   // partition the vector, alive to the left of the partition, 
   // dead to the right of the partition.  An iterator to the partitioning
   // point is returned.
   auto iter = std::stable_partition(agents.begin(), agents.end(), 
                                     [](Agent *a) { return a->isAlive();});

   // null out all the dead ones in the grid and call delete.
   std::for_each(iter, agents.end(), 
                      [&](Agent* a) {grid[a->getY()][a->getX()] = nullptr; delete a;});

  // erase dead ones from vector.
  agents.erase(iter, agents.end());
}
```

As the comment stated, the partition simply moves the pointers around, placing the live agents to the left of the partition, and the dead to the right of the partition.

Then in one loop, resets the grid and calls `delete` on each of the dead ones.
Then at the very end of this, a single call to `erase` is done, not multiple calls to `erase` as your original code is doing.

In addition, note the erasure is a single call, and the only items erased are the ones at the tail end of the `vector` (that's why I partitioned the dead agents to the right of the partition).  Erasing items from the back of a vector is much more efficient than erasing items in the middle or front of the vector.

If the order of the items in the `agent` vector is not important, then `std::partition` can be used, which would be even more efficient than `std::stable_partition`.  The `std::partition` would simply goes through the vector, and without maintaining the original order, places the live and dead agents to the left and right of the partition point, respectively.

If you didn't know `std::partition`, a better implementation of your original code would be to go through and bring the alive agents to the front of the vector by traversing the vector once and doing swaps in a strategic manner, then record where the last alive agent was swapped to, and then erase starting from there (yes it takes some code to do this, but you get the idea).  That is in essence what this solution (using either `std::partition` or `std::stable_partition`) is doing.

Comment: I suspected you were a C++ god, then I read your bio and my suspicion turned to confirmation! :P